# How can i handle an html array with java and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

okay I have a simple html form script I have tried so many way to post the data to Ajax and have Ajax echo each line out separately one after another but unfortunately what ever I have tried just don't work for me I am new to java and Ajax here's my html form if any one can show me any example scripts or sample way to make my script echo each line of the form separately 1 by 1 .

heres my html form

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script> 
</head>
<form method="post">
    <div align="center">
        <textarea name="mp" cols="60" rows="10">0|1|2</textarea>
        <br />

        Delim:
        <input type="text" name="delim" value="|" size="1" />&nbsp;

        data1:
        <input type="text" name="mail" value="0" size="1" />&nbsp;

        data2:
        <input type="text" name="prx" value="1" size="1" />&nbsp;

    <input type="submit" value=" send " name="btn-submit" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

?>
```

Comment: show us the attempted ajax

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Show us the code for what you're trying and maybe we can help.

Comment: if you read my question I am asking people to point me in the write direction or show me example on how to incorporate it into my script

Comment: You seem to be confusing the programming language PHP with a client-server communication protocol for JavaScript (AJAX). And I also fear that a database backend may play into your problem. Please try to clarify what you are actually asking. As it stands right now your question makes little to no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you are asking. But I created a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/JWkmQ/.

I basically added some script that aggregates the data and attempts to post them somewhere:

```
$('#doit').on('click', function() {
    var data = {};
    $('textarea').each(function() {
        data[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    $('[type="text"]').each(function() {
        data[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(data);
    $.post('http://example.com/datalistener', JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

Of course, you will need some code on the server side to handle the request. I would suggest you code yourself some nodejs backend like this: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/.

Please stay away from PHP ;)